# .NET Framework C# OIDC Add PKCE to Amazon AWS Cognito

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-cognito, openid-connect, pkce

I have three applications that all use different .NET methodologies (I don't know a better word off-hand). I have a .NET Core 3.1 Web App, a .NET Framework 4.8 MVC Web App, and a .NET Framework 4.6 Web Forms Application. All written in C#.

All three require that I use PKCE (Proof Key for Code Exchange). All three applications use Amazon AWS Cognito for Authentication and Authorization. Everything works well except that the two non-.NET Core apps don't use PKCE and I need them to.

*Okay, so my main thinking here is that there might possibly be some "easy breezy" way I can add PKCE support to the .NET Framework applications via the Startup.Auth.cs file or some such were we define the OIDC Auth*.

**What I've done:**

I've been able to find some online articles on how to add PKCE to a site, but they're all manual mechanisms of adding the necessary bits to the query string.

- [How to secure the Cognito login flow with a state nonce and PKCE](https://advancedweb.hu/how-to-secure-the-cognito-login-flow-with-a-state-nonce-and-pkce/)
- [Authorize endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html)
- [ASP.NET Core using Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE)](https://www.scottbrady91.com/openid-connect/aspnet-core-using-proof-key-for-code-exchange-pkce)

The .NET Core article was particularly useful for my identification of how my .NET Core app works, but it doesn't help with the other two apps. Overall, the process seems to be broken down into the following steps:

1. Create a [Code_Verifier](https://medium.com/identity-beyond-borders/what-the-heck-is-pkce-40662e801a76#:%7E:text=code_verifier%20%E2%80%94%20The%20code%20verifier%20should,a%20maximum%20of%20128%20characters.) Call it VERIFIER.
2. SHA256 that Code_Verifier and base 64 encode it. Call it the CHALLENGE.
3. Add this to the query string we send to the "authorize" endpoint along with a code_challenge_method which must, for Cognito, be set to S256.
4. Add to the query string that we send to the "token" endpoint, the Code_Verifier with the value VERIFIER.

In essence, we could manually add the following to the query string that calls the "authorize" endpoint: "&code_challenge=CHALLENGE&code_challenge_method=S256".

And to the query string that calls the "token" endpoint: "&code_verifier=VERIFIER". ([I'm pretty sure this token endpoint is a POST](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html).)

I think that's it. So, I *could* add this stuff manually, somehow, to these calls. However, I would prefer to let the .NET Framework magically do the work for me.

**Hence, my overall question. Is there a way for me to modify the .NET code I have to have PKCE added by modifying my code without manually adding it.**

I've searched the web, the Microsoft site, and I've fiddled around with the actual code, but I'm not finding any mechanisms for adding PKCE in these methods.

**My Examples from my code:**

.NET Framework Web Forms App:

```
   public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager()
        });

        ConfigureIdentityProviders(app, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    }

    private void ConfigureIdentityProviders(IAppBuilder app, string signInAsType)
    {
        var saveTokens = true;
        var validateIssuer = true;
        var saveTokensValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Cognito.SaveTokens"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(saveTokensValue))
        {
            saveTokens = bool.TryParse(saveTokensValue, out var outResult) && outResult;
        }
        var validateIssuerValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Cognito.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(validateIssuerValue))
        {
            validateIssuer = bool.TryParse(validateIssuerValue, out var outResult) && outResult;
        }

        app.UseCustomOidcAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Cognito.ClientId"],
                ResponseType = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Cognito.ResponseType"],
                Authority = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Cognito.Authority"],
                MetadataAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Cognito.MetadataAddress"],
                ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Cognito.ClientSecret"],
                RedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Cognito.RedirectUri"],
                SaveTokens = saveTokens,
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Cognito.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType"],
                    RoleClaimType = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Cognito.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType"],
                    ValidateIssuer = validateIssuer
                },
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = async (context) =>
                    {
                        var removePortOnRedirectIdentifierValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Cognito.RemovePortOnRedirectToIdentityProvider"];
                        var convertResult = bool.TryParse(removePortOnRedirectIdentifierValue, out var removePortOnRedirectIdentifier);
                        if (removePortOnRedirectIdentifier && convertResult)
                        {
                            var builder = new UriBuilder(context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri)
                            {
                                Scheme = "https",
                                Port = -1
                            };

                            context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = builder.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                },
                Scope = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Cognito.Scope"],
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = signInAsType
            }
        );
    }
```

My .NET Framework MVC App:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var loginPath = AuthorizationSettings.Instance.LoginPath;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(loginPath))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("No value specified for EiHubSettings LoginPath");


    // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(SecurityDbContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<SecurityUserManager>(SecurityUserManager.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<SecurityRoleManager>(SecurityRoleManager.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<SecuritySignInManager>(SecuritySignInManager.Create);
    
    // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
    // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
    // Configure the sign in cookie
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString(loginPath),
        CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager(),
        ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(
            Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Cognito.CookieLifetimeInSeconds"])),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
        {
            // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
            // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
            OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<SecurityUserManager, SecurityUser, int>(
                validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) => user.CreateIdentityAsync(manager),
                getUserIdCallback: (user) => user.GetUserId<int>())
        }
    });            
    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

    // Enables the application to temporarily store user information when they are verifying the second factor in the two-factor authentication process.
    app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

    // Enables the application to remember the second login verification factor such as phone or email.
    // Once you check this option, your second step of verification during the login process will be remembered on the device where you logged in from.
    // This is similar to the RememberMe option when you log in.
    app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

    if(AppSettingsConfigSingleton.UsesCognito)
    {
        ConfigureIdentityProviders(app, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    }
}

private void ConfigureIdentityProviders(IAppBuilder app, string signInAsType)
{
    var saveTokens = true;
    var validateIssuer = true;
    var saveTokensValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Cognito.SaveTokens"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(saveTokensValue))
    {
        saveTokens = bool.TryParse(saveTokensValue, out var outResult) && outResult;
    }
    var validateIssuerValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Cognito.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(validateIssuerValue))
    {
        validateIssuer = bool.TryParse(validateIssuerValue, out var outResult) && outResult;
    }
    
    app.UseCustomOidcAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Cognito.ClientId"],
            ResponseType = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Cognito.ResponseType"],
            Authority = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Cognito.Authority"],
            MetadataAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Cognito.MetadataAddress"],
            ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Cognito.ClientSecret"],
            RedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Cognito.RedirectUri"],
            SaveTokens = saveTokens,
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                SecurityTokenValidated = context =>
                {
                    var redirectUri = "/account/openidlogincallback";
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.AuthenticationTicket.Properties.RedirectUri))
                    {
                        redirectUri += $"?returnUrl={context.AuthenticationTicket.Properties.RedirectUri}";
                    }
                    context.AuthenticationTicket.Properties.RedirectUri = redirectUri;

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
                {
                    var removePortOnRedirectIdentifierValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Cognito.RemovePortOnRedirectToIdentityProvider"];
                    var convertResult = bool.TryParse(removePortOnRedirectIdentifierValue, out var removePortOnRedirectIdentifier);
                    if (removePortOnRedirectIdentifier && convertResult)
                    {
                        var builder = new UriBuilder(context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri)
                        {
                            Scheme = "https", Port = -1
                        };

                        context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = builder.ToString();
                    }

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            },
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                NameClaimType = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Cognito.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType"],
                RoleClaimType = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Cognito.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType"],
                ValidateIssuer = validateIssuer
            },
            Scope = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Cognito.Scope"],
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = signInAsType
        }
    );
}
```

The .NET Core 3.1 app (yes, I know we need to upgrade to .NET 6), has a "built-in" mechanism for adding PKCE (which befuddled me for the longest time until I saw this -- this option is not explicitly set in my code, but as you can see, it's by default turned on):

[image]

So, I'm hoping against hope, that there is something similar in the .NET Framework

Answer (score 0):

In the `StartUp` class:

```
//  Referred to in CustomOidcHandler
public const string CODE_VERIFIER = "code_verifier";

private const string _CODE_CHALLENGE = "code_challenge";
private const string _CODE_CHALLENGE_METHOD = "code_challenge_method";
private const string _CODE_CHALLENGE_METHOD_S256 = "S256";
```

In the `ConfigureIdentityProviders` in `Startup`

```
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
                {
                    var removePortOnRedirectIdentifierValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Cognito.RemovePortOnRedirectToIdentityProvider"];
                    var convertResult = bool.TryParse(removePortOnRedirectIdentifierValue, out var removePortOnRedirectIdentifier);
                    if (removePortOnRedirectIdentifier && convertResult)
                    {
                        var builder = new UriBuilder(context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri)
                        {
                            Scheme = "https",
                            Port = -1
                        };

                        context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = builder.ToString();
                    }

                    //
                    //  We need the code_verifier value passed to the CustomOidcHandler
                    //  so that it can be added to the POST to the /token endpoint
                    //
                    string codeVerifier = GenerateCodeVerifier();
                    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(CODE_VERIFIER);
                    cookie.Value = codeVerifier;
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

                    //
                    //  Add the code_challenge to the GET request to Cognito
                    //
                    //  Methodology found here: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/4874
                    //
                    string codeChallenge = GenerateCodeChallenge(codeVerifier);
                    context.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter(_CODE_CHALLENGE, codeChallenge);
                    context.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter(_CODE_CHALLENGE_METHOD, _CODE_CHALLENGE_METHOD_S256);

                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
```

In my `CustomOidcHandler` file, the `GetTokens` method:

```
    string codeVerifier = Request != null && Request.Cookies != null && Request.Cookies[Startup.CODE_VERIFIER] != null ? Request.Cookies[Startup.CODE_VERIFIER] : string.Empty;
    Dictionary<string, string> post = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"client_id", options.ClientId},
        {"client_secret", options.ClientSecret},
        {"grant_type", "authorization_code"},
        {"code", authorizationCode},
        {"redirect_uri", options.RedirectUri},
        {Startup.CODE_VERIFIER, codeVerifier}
    };
```

Hence, the only way is to "manually" add it.